# Writing a script for Facebook

Tags: scripts, facebook

I want to write a script that will allow Facebook to open in Chromium and then choose most recent on the news feed. How do I get started to try this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the url in the following code blocks with the desired url.

```
#!/bin/bash

chromium-browser "https://askubuntu.com/questions/967003/writing-a-script-for-facebook" & disown
```

Or an example for xfce desktop launcher `~/.config/autostart/Facebook.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=Facebook
Comment=
Exec=chromium-browser "https://askubuntu.com/questions/967003/writing-a-script-for-facebook"
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```